# Bug in std::wstring?

Tags: c++

I found some very strange behavior of std::wstring.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::wstring someString = L"Some dummy string";

    std::wstring base1 = L"Base1 ";
    std::wstring base2 = L"Base2 ";
    std::wstring second = L"Second";

    base1 += second.at(0) + L" ";

    base2 += second.at(0);
    base2 += L" ";

    return 0;
}
```

The base1 and base2 output should be the same, but there are not.
Base1 is actually doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you edit to show expected + actual output? is it windows? which version of visual c++ if it is the case? Cannot be a bug in a spec.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
second.at(0) + L" "
```

This expression doesn't do what you expect. `at(0)` returns a `wchar_t`, which is really an integer. `L" "` is a wide string literal, which is implicitly converted to a `wchar_t const*`. So in the expression above, you are doing pointer arithmetic, adding whatever the value of `L'S'` is (probably the same as the ASCII value of `S`, which is 83, I believe). This gives you a pointer far outside the range of the string literal, which is only 2 characters. The end result is undefined behavior.

To get the effect you are probably going for, you can make one of your operands a `wstring`.

```
base1 += second.at(0) + std::wstring(L" ");
```

Probably simpler in this case would be to just use 2 statements.

```
base1 += second.at(0);
base1 += L' ';
```